# Problem with fopen error using getopt optarg

Tags: c, fopen, getopt

Running it does not open the file that i'm parsing with optarg in option -w.

I run with ./programname -w filename.txt

filename.txt is in the same directory with exe file etc...

I post here a part of code to let you understand, thank you!

P.S. Sorry for my bad english!

```
    while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "lw")) != -1) 
        switch(opt) {
            case 'l': {
                //... do something ...
            } break;

            case 'w': {
                int counter = 0;
                FILE* ifp = fopen(optarg, "r"); 
                CHECK_OPEN_FILE(ifp, optarg);
                while(fgets(buffer, 256, ifp) != NULL)
                    counter += wordscounter(buffer);
                fprintf(stdout, "File has %d words.\n", counter);
                fclose(ifp);
            }break;

            case '?': {
                if(optopt == '-')
                    break;
                fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Option -%c unrecognized...\n", optopt);
            } break;

        }
```

*In this part of code i have a problem:*

```
FILE* ifp = fopen(optarg, "r"); 
CHECK_OPEN_FILE(ifp, optarg);
```

Comment: `fopen` being `NULL` means check `errno`.

Comment: HI, welcome to SO please provide a better title  than "Can someone help me to find the error in this C code?"

Comment: I really don't understand what you are asking.  The grammar of your sentence "that is unable to open the file.txt parsed by comand line running as ./a.out -w esfile.txt" isn't sensible.

Comment: Try *creating* a file in the same way (use a different name) and see if it appears in the same place as the one you want to read.

Comment: `while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "lw:")) != -1) {` <<-- I added a`:` . [and *please* remove these silly `{}` blocks after the case labels]

Comment: Sorry if my question was not accurate. I edited the post trying to make it clearer and more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If such a character is followed by a colon, the option requires an
> argument

You are missing `:` for option `w`. You should have `lw:` specifying that `w` has a value. Else `optarg` is null

[The man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt)